# Different result unrolling loop - Python generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

When I append two generators to a list using a loop the first generator duplicates the second generator's output. When I unroll the loop I get different output as I expected.

The following code demonstrates the issue.

```
import itertools

iterators = itertools.tee(itertools.repeat(('a', 0), 5), 2)
result = []
result.append(r[0] for r in iterators[0])
result.append(r[1] for r in iterators[1])

# As expected
print('Written out...')
print(list(result[0])) # ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
print(list(result[1])) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


# Now do it again but use a loop
iterators = itertools.tee(itertools.repeat(('a', 0), 5), 2)
result = []
for index in [0, 1]:
    result.append(r[index] for r in iterators[index])

# This time both lists are of the second item.
print('With a loop...')
print(list(result[0])) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] <--- Huh?!
print(list(result[1])) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why does the loop version not work as I expected? What can I do about it?

---

## Solution

Now this is closed as a duplicate I can't post another answer, but for the record, here is the solution I used finally.

The problem as pointed out by @MikeMüller is that the instance of `index` that indexes `r` is late-bound. The following forces early-binding by making a new local variable instance `i` for each value of `index` in the loop:

```
for index, it in enumerate(iterators):
    g = lambda i: (r[i] for r in it) # force early binding on index
    result.append(g(index))
```

(I also liked Mike's suggestion to use generators all the way down, but unfortuantely I need the outer generator (for `result`) to be materialised so I can refer repeatedly to the individual elements in `result`. But `list(result)` has the same behaviour as my original loop code.)

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Comment: You only have one `index` variable. Both generators use it. Same as the JavaScript thing, I’ll try to find a Python duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Remember the generator doesn't run until you call `list` and you're capturing `index`. Stick the print inside the loop and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

### Fix

You need to consume your iterators earlier:

```
for index in [0, 1]:
    result.append(list(r[index] for r in iterators[index]))
```

to get the equivalent effect.

Now:

```
print('With a loop...')
print(result[0])
print(result[1])
```

Output:

```
With a loop...
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To illustrate this set `index = 0` after the loop:

```
iterators = itertools.tee(itertools.repeat(('a', 0), 5), 2)
result = []
for index in [0, 1]:
    result.append(r[index] for r in iterators[index])
index = 0
print('With a loop...')
print(list(result[0]))
print(list(result[1]))
```

Now the first part of `tee` is used twice because `r[index]` always meàns `r[0]`:

```
With a loop...
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

### Reason

The `index` is applied lazily, i.e. when you actually convert to a list.
Since the index is `1` after the loop, it uses this `1` twice in `r[index]` and you get the second item in the iterator twice.

### Alternative

Use iterators all the way till consumption:

```
iterators = itertools.tee(itertools.repeat(('a', 0), 5), 2)
result = ((r[index] for r in iterators[index]) for index in [0, 1])
for res in result:
    print(list(res))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This is also the reason why if `append` is replaced with `extend` it works great: It consumes the iterators on time.

Comment: My first guess was that `index` was being closed over, so it was taking on its last value (1) for both generators. So I tried setting index = -1 after the loop expecting to get an index out of range exception. But I didn't and nothing was changed. (I realise now this is because -1 means the last element, which in context is the same as 1.)

Comment: Thanks. Your 'alternative' is the right answer as far as I am concerned. If consuming the iterators earlier was an option then the obvious solution would be to turn the initial iterator of tuples into a list and extract the individual elements with a couple of simple list comprehensions. Far simpler, but no good if the entire sequence won't fit in memory.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that while the first `index` in the generator expression is evaluated lazily the second one is [evaluated immediately](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding) (linked from 1st duplicate), which explains why I didn't see the generator exhausted after the first result.. You really have to know the details to use this stuff safely! :-)

Comment: Yes, `iterators[index]` is evaluate immediately but  `r[index]` is evaluated lazily. This is because `r[index]` is the "loop variable" and is evaluated potentially multiple times whereas `iterators[index]` is evaluated only once.